# Почему это не является ошибкой в синтаксисе?

Tags: php

```
echo "Hello, world!";;;
;;
;
```

Я думал всегда что скрипт не будет работать, объясните почему работает?

Comment: В чем именно ошибка?

Comment: точка с запятой отделяет инструкции. много точек запятой означает лишь то, что впереди пустая инструкция

Comment: @АлексейШиманский странно я думал что тут как минимум сработает E_NOTICE

Comment: синтаксический сахар...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Точка с запятой отделяет инструкции. 
Теоретически `echo "Hello, world";` выглядит так:

```
{
    Вывести строчку "Hello, world!" 
}
```

То есть существует некий блок, изолированный, инструкция, которая должна выполниться.

Много точек запятой означает лишь то, что в теории это будет выглядеть так

```
{}

{}

{}
```

Куча пустых блоков, в которых ничего нет и нечему исполняться.

А сами по себе `{}` - вполне легальная конструкция...Которой, как мы знаем отделяются всякие условия `if` или тела функций `function test() {}` и т.д.

Например, можно спокойно написать:

```
<?php    
{
    echo 'Вот оно чё, Михалыч<br />';
    $magic = 'Это магия какая-то!';
    echo $magic;
}
?>
```

И оно будет работать